# Django: Database efficiency - currently accessed twice

Tags: python, django

I have the following function that is called via signal. 1) check if incluencer exists. 2) Increase discount by +1. Currently, I hit the database twice. Is there a better way to write that? Additionally, I wonder I can check 2) all on a database level so I don't need the for-loop.

```
@receiver(signal=charge_succeeded)
@transaction.atomic
def create_influencer_transaction(sender, order, charge, **kwargs):
    order_exists = Transaction.objects.filter(order=order).exists()
    if order_exists:
        return None

    # 1) Check if influencer exists
    first_order_item = order.order_items.first()
    influencer = first_order_item.social_referral
    if not influencer:
        return None

    total_points_earned = order.order_items.aggregate(
        total=Sum(
            F('unit_points_earned') * F('quantity'),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )['total'] or 0

    Transaction.objects.create(
        [...]
    )

    # 2) Redeemed amount + 1
    for order_item in order.order_items.all():
        social_discount = order_item.social_discount
        if social_discount:
            social_discount.redeemed_amount = F('redeemed_amount') + 1
            social_discount.save(update_fields=['redeemed_amount'])
            break
```

models.py

```
class OrderItem(AbstractItem, AbstractDiscountItem, AbstractSocialItem):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        [...]
    )
    social_discount = models.ForeignKey(
        'discounts.SocialDiscount',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='order_items',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )   # PROTECT = don't allow to delete the discount if an order_item exists


class SocialDiscount(AbstractDiscount):

    event = models.OneToOneField(
        [...]
    )  # CASCADE = delete the discount if the event is deleted
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(
        [...]
    )
```

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes of course. I added the models.py schema. It's handled as `ForeignKey`. Many order_items can have the same `socialdiscount`

Comment: Thanks for that, just one last thing, am I safe assuming `redeemed_amount` is an `IntegerField`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step 2 can be done entirely in DB by [filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [limiting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) your `order_items`. And then [updating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) it to contain the desired value. Note that the [`F` objects documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) already mention that use of a queryset update method. So we could imagine something like:

```
order.order_items.filter(social_discount__isnull=False)[:1].update(social_discount__redeemed_amount=F('social_discount__redeemed_amount') + 1)
```

Except this doesn't work:

1. we cannot use `update` after slicing a queryset;
2. we cannot update fields of related models anyway.

Instead we must use the relationship backwards and filter/update on the `SocialDiscount` model, the filter being the subset of `OrderItem`s we are interested in:

```
order_item = order.order_items.filter(social_discount__isnull=False)[:1]
# Note that order_item is still a queryset and has not hit the database yet
SocialDiscount.objects.filter(order_items__in=order_item).update(redeemed_amount=F('redeemed_amount') + 1)
```

Even though this only hit the database once, this will update **all** `SocialDiscount` objects that are related to the one `order_item` specified by the queryset above. If it ever can mean that more than one object is updated and you don't want that, you can still remove the `for` loop using this two-queries code:

```
social_discount = order.order_items.filter(social_discount__isnull=False).select_related('social_discount').first().social_discount
social_discount.redeemed_amount = F('redeemed_amount') + 1
social_discount.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question for my understanding. `SocialDiscount.objects.filter(order_items` > Will filter then go into the model where my order_items are saved and look for the SocialDiscount used in that specific order_item?

Comment: @JoeyCoder See update.